# Format number in chart tooltip

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart

I am using WinForm charting library. The chart shows tooltip after adding the following code:

```
series.ToolTip = "#VALY";
```

However, the number appears as 12345.6789. How can I format it to show 12,345 only?

Edit: It is documented in the below link. Not sure which format to use to show comma and hide decimal digits.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/dd456687(v=vs.100)

Comment: Please show us *all relevant* code in question, without it, it will be difficult to explain what may be wrong; I already have assumptions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code fix was required:

```
series.ToolTip = "#VALY{#,###}";
```